# How to install cloudera impala on EMR?

Tags: hadoop, hive, cloudera, amazon-emr, impala

Is there anyway i can install the only impala without cloudera manager and without cdh. I will be using the apache version of hadoop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is absolutely possible. Add the repository into your `sources.list` file and update the repository after that.

> deb [arch=amd64]
>   http://archive.cloudera.com/impala/ubuntu/precise/amd64/impala
>   precise-impala1 contrib deb-src
>   http://archive.cloudera.com/impala/ubuntu/precise/amd64/impala
>   precise-impala1 contrib

After that, it's merely :

```
sudo apt-get install impala                (Binaries for daemons)
sudo apt-get install impala-server         (Service start/stop script)
sudo apt-get install impala-state-store    (Service start/stop script)
```

But do not forget to meet all the prerequisites. For a detailed info you can go [here](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera-content/cloudera-docs/Impala/latest/Installing-and-Using-Impala/Installing-and-Using-Impala.html)

Comment: I tried installing the impala on EMR two time once on 32-bit ubuntu. The i came to know they don't support it. After that i also did on 64-bit ubuntu. Then also it didn't work. Now i am having doubt whether cloudera support the integration with apache hadoop or not. Would you like to comment on that. So that's why i remove it as a correct answer

Comment: I have installed it myself on my machine(Ubuntu 64-bit). You might have to struggle with the configuration though. But installation is quite straightforward.

Comment: i agreed you must have installed on 64-bit machine. But, you were using the cdh or apache hadoop? i am using apache hadoop. Also, if i want to install it on 32-bit ubuntu local machine without cloudera manager will it work?

Comment: Apache Hadoop-1.0.4. I don't know about 32-bit machines. I am on 64-bit Ubuntu.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32070/discussion-between-naresh-and-tariq)

Comment: I dont see sources.list  in emr master node can anyone help ?

Answer (score 1):

You can view detailed instructions on how to install and use Impala with Amazon EMR here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/emr-impala.html

Comment: There is no need to install Imapala on EMR. Just create a cluster and use it.

Answer (score -1):

EMR is based on a Amazon Hadoop distribution that runs on top of Debian squeeze. So, yes it's possible using Cloudera's DEB repo.

You will need to SSH to your EMR master node, find the address on EMR console.

You will also need to enable security rules on the security group you have assigned to your EMR cluster, if you intend to connect to Impala using a JDBC/ODBC client form the outside world.